# How to pass native headers to disconnect event?

Tags: spring-mvc, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I've been trying to pass native headers to disconnect event using StompJS but I don't know how to declare them (I guess it must be a similar approach like for connect event described here: http://www.sergialmar.com/2014/03/detect-websocket-connects-and-disconnects-in-spring-4/)

The event listener looks following:

```
@Component
public class DocumentStompDisconnectEvent implements ApplicationListener<SessionDisconnectEvent> {

    @Override
    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

        String documentId = sha.getNativeHeader("documentId").get(0);
        System.out.println("Disconnect event [documentId: " + documentId + "]");        
    }
}
```

When I try to pass those headers to connect event, then it works fine:

```
function connect() {
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({userId: "${userId}", documentId: "${documentId}"}, function (frame) {
```

but at the moment I don't have any idea how to pass them to disconnect event.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?